# What are some accurate User Agent parsers for node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, user-agent

I want to get the device type from the user agent but most of the parsers on git do not give a valid result for a Mac. I need the parser to return device for "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

The hardware is not specified by the user agent string. The best answer you can get from what you provided is that the OS is running on an Intel base Mac so it's not an iPhone or iPad but could be any actual Macintosh computer.

Depending on what you are trying to do you may find this article on (User Agent vs Feature Detection)[http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/detection/] useful.